# Junit testing expected value

Tags: java, testing, junit, junit5

I have the following method to test in Junit

```
public static boolean saveLocationData(String student, String city, String location){
    boolean status=false;
    try {
        Connection mySqlConn = MySQLConn.getConnection();
        String mySqlQuery = "INSERT INTO locations VALUES ( ?, ?, ?)";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement =    mySqlConn.prepareStatement(mySqlQuery);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, student);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, city); 
        preparedStatement.setString(3, location); 
        preparedStatement.execute();                                                                 
    } catch (Exception exception){
        /////
    }
    return status;
}
```

And the testing I have tried is :

```
final void  saveLOCATIONData() {                                   
    boolean validation = LocationDao.saveLocationData("student", "nyc", "usa");
    assertTrue(validation);

    //doesn’t exist
    validation = LocationDao.saveLocationData("example", "example", "example");
    assertFalse(validation);
}
```

When I run the test it says that the expected value should be true, instead is false, while this is the actual data that I have in the database. What can be causing the problem?

Comment: Please update your question with valid example. E.g. ```this``` is reserved word.

Comment: Also, what does this method return? If we ignore the fact that "this" is an invalid variable name, this method will always return `false`.

Comment: I just updated the code @Mensur Qulami

Comment: I just updated it @zforgo

Comment: @user12934352 still, `status` value is `false` always. Is it updated anywhere?

Comment: @Mensur Qulami I have used the same logic (status) for others methods to test and they work, only this one doesnt function. Why do u think is always false?

Comment: I don't know much about them, but in this one, you declare status as false, and return it at the end of the function without updating it anywhere, and you are also catching all the exceptions, therefore the method will always return false no matter what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:-

```
public static boolean saveLocationData(String student, String city, String location){
    boolean status=false;
    try {
        Connection mySqlConn = MySQLConn.getConnection();
        String mySqlQuery = "INSERT INTO locations VALUES ( ?, ?, ?)";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement =    mySqlConn.prepareStatement(mySqlQuery);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, student);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, city); 
        preparedStatement.setString(3, location); 
        preparedStatement.execute();
        status=true;                                                                 
    } catch (Exception exception){
        /////
    }
    return status;
}

*************************************************
final void  saveLOCATIONData() {                                   
    boolean validation = LocationDao.saveLocationData("student", "nyc", "usa");
    assertTrue(validation);

    //doesn’t exist
    validation = LocationDao.saveLocationData("example", "example", "example");
    assertFalse(validation);
}
```